# .htaccess access to web root and sub-folders

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the .htaccess in the main folder (/public_html) with the following lines in it. These are for an application i have installed on my domain.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems like this rule makes every sub-folders inaccessible. For example i have a sub folder called /public_htm/public. I want this sub-folder and all of it's contents to be accessible to public. If i put a .htaccess  file in this subfolder, what lines it needs to have to give access to it's content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yeap that works. many thank you @anubhava for the super quick answer :)

Comment: You're most welcome. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.